# Forcing two parameters of a generic method to have the same concrete type

Tags: java, generics, methods

How can I have a method with two parameters, with both parameters having the same concrete type?

For example,

```
boolean equals(Object a, Object b)
```

allows for `a` of any type and `b` of any type.

I want to force such that `a` and `b` have the same concrete type. I tried

```
<T> boolean equals(T a, T b)
```

and inputting a `Date` and a `String` to that method, expecting a compile-time error, but I get no errors, since T will resolve to `? extends Serializable & Comparable`, since both `Date` and `String` implements `Serializable` and `Comparable`.

Comment: Why would you ever want to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't, basically. There's no way of doing that. Even if you could do it for a simple call to prohibit arguments of different types, it could always be bypassed using a cast:

```
equals((Object) date, (Object) string)
```

If you're interested in the *execution-time* types of the arguments, you can only test that at execution time. There's no way of the compiler knowing whether an argument of type `Date` has a value which is a reference to *precisely* a `java.util.Date` or some subclass.

Comment: Thank you for the lightning-fast answer.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is your method's signature becomes

```
<? extends Object> boolean equals(? extends Object a, ? extends Object b)
```

which doesn't give you any options. Even if you call

```
equals(new Date(), "hello world");
```

the compiler doesn't even need to break a sweat and determine the lowest common ancestor for your parameter types.

**Edit**

Interesting fact. I knew what I wrote above was true, but it still looked a bit weird. So I tested

```
<T> boolean equals(T a, T b) {
    return true;
}

<T,E> boolean equals(T a, E b) {
    return true;
}
```

Which the compiler yelled at. The reason is that the compiler indeed doesn't make a difference and just rewrites both methods as

```
boolean equals(? extends Object a, ? extends Object b)
```

which after type erasure becomes

```
boolean equals(Object a, Object b)
```

which is the exact same signature. Indeed, if I keep your method `equals(T,T)` and I add another method with signature `equals(Object, Object)` the compiler continues to say that I have the same method declared elsewhere.

**Long story short**, your method `equals(T,T)` is the same as `equals(Object, Object)` due to type erasure and thus you can't force the same parameter type, at least at compile time, *unless* you specifically implement `equals` methods for each.

Answer (score 0):

As other users have mentioned, there is no way to force this for a particular method. But you can, if it is possible for you, move this method to a separate parameterised class and then use the parameter in the method signature.

For example: This is the method where I wanted to enforce same argument types. (I was trying to get diff between o1 and o2)

`public List<Change> getChanges(Object o1, Object o2);`

I encapsulated this method inside a parameterised class.

```
public class DiffGenerator<T> { 
  public List<Change> getChanges(T o1, T o2) { 
  //code
 }
}
```

This can be used as:
`List<Change> changes = new DiffGenerator<MyClass>().getChanges(myClassOld, myClassNew);`