# Shouldn't the type T in addToCollection(T[] a, Collection<T> c) be the same?

Tags: java, generics, collections

I don't understand why the following code works:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Integer[] arr=new Integer[]{1,2,3};
            ArrayList<Object> al=new ArrayList<>();
            addToCollection(arr, al);
        }
        static <T> void addToCollection(T[] a, Collection<T> c)
        {
            for(T o:a)
                c.add(o);
        }
    }
```

Shouldn't it be:

...

```
static <T> void addToCollection(T[] a, Collection<? super T> c)
```

...?

Shouldn't the type T be the same during the call?

As said in the comments, my question is "which type is inferred for T". Since the code is working, I assume the "higher" type in the hierarchy is inferred.

Comment: The same as what?

Comment: If you have an array of `Bicycle`, shouldn't you be able to add it to a collection of `Vehicle`?

Comment: He's asking why he's allowed to pass `ArrayList<Object>` and `Integer[]`.  The question is which type is inferred for `T`, and I believe it is `Object` but don't have a specific reference to the JLS at this time.

Comment: arr is an Object[] (because Integer[] is an Object[]), and ArrayList<Object> is a Collection<Object>, so that compiles.

Comment: Note that `Object[] x = new Integer[10];` compiles but `ArrayList<Object> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();` does not.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25867191/forcing-two-parameters-of-a-generic-method-to-have-the-same-concrete-type

Comment: I'm not sure that is a dup. The fundamental question is which type is inferred for `T` in the statement `addToCollection(arr, al)`, i.e. what are the rules for type inference when one type reference is a supertype of another reference using the same type variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `arr` and `al` are subtypes of Object, so that's what you're getting. If you change your `addToCollection` function to have a return type, this happens:

```
public static class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] arr=new Integer[]{1,2,3};
        ArrayList<Object> al=new ArrayList<>();
        Collection<Object> objects = addToCollection(arr, al);  // Compiles
        Collection<Integer> numbers = addToCollection(arr, al); // Doesn't compile
    }

    static <T> Collection<T> addToCollection(T[] a, Collection<T> c)
    {
        for(T o:a) // Behold the side effect
            c.add(o);

        return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, the second `addToCollection(arr, al)` returns a `Collection<Object>` , right?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't compile because the type is incorrect. It's only there to show it.